# C# List variable

Tags: c#

guys. 
How can I get data from List in another file? I try this way, but it's don't work:

CharacterController.cs

```
public class CharacterController
{
public static List<Character> Characters { get; set; }

public static async Task LoadCharacterData(Client player)
{
  var filter = new BsonDocument("NameOfTable", player.Name);
  var characters = await DatabaseManager.Characters.Find(filter).ToListAsync();

  List<Character> Characters = new List<Character>();
  foreach (var character in characters)
  {
    Characters.Add(new Character
      {
        Name = character.Name,
        Surname = character.Surname
      }
    );
  }

  Console.WriteLine("TEST: " + Characters[0].Name + Characters[0].Surname); //It's working
}
```

In another file:

```
public void OnPlayerDownloaded(Client player)
{
  CharacterController.LoadCharacterData(player);
  Console.WriteLine("TEST: " + CharacterController.Characters[0].Name + CharacterController.Characters[0].Surname); // It's don't working
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific on what "It's don't working" means? - I suspect you are getting a null reference exception because `LoadCharacterData` has not initialized `Characters` (notice it is an async method). In that case, then you are successful in accesing a field defined in another file. By the way, `List<T>` is not thread safe.

Comment: Yea, sorry. I had error: 

System.NullReferenceException: The object reference does not point to an instance of the object.

You're right.
Maybe you will advise how best to remake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, the problem is that you need to have some means to synchronize access to the `List<Character> Characters`.

Notice the signature of the method `LoadCharacterData`:

```
public static async Task LoadCharacterData(Client player)
{
    // ...
}
```

It is an **async** method. It will not run synchonously. That means that when you call `CharacterController.LoadCharacterData(player);` you would need to wait for it to finish.

You can accomplish this by making the caller `async` and using `await`. Although, I suspect you can't change the signature of `OnPlayerDownloaded`. In that case I'd take the retunred `Task` and wait on it:

```
public void OnPlayerDownloaded(Client player)
{
    var task = CharacterController.LoadCharacterData(player);
    task.Wait(); // <---
    Console.WriteLine("TEST: " + CharacterController.Characters[0].Name + CharacterController.Characters[0].Surname);
}
```

---

Note: on your code, you must be getting a warning on the following line:

```
List<Character> Characters = new List<Character>();
```

Here, you are not using the property. You are creating a local variable with the same name.

---

Now, there is another hidden issue... `List<Character>` is not thread-safe. Consider the problem it would cause if you had two calls to `LoadCharacterData` running at the same time! - `List<Character>` is not designed to handle that.

I suggest to rewrite `LoadCharacterData` to return `Task<List<Characater>>` and have it return the `List<Character>` instead of writing it to the public property:

```
public static async Task<List<Character>> LoadCharacterData(Client player)
{
  var filter = new BsonDocument("NameOfTable", player.Name);
  var characters = await DatabaseManager.Characters.Find(filter).ToListAsync();

  List<Character> result = new List<Character>();
  foreach (var character in characters)
  {
    result.Add(new Character
      {
        Name = character.Name,
        Surname = character.Surname
      }
    );
  }
  return result;
}
```

Alternatively, you could consider to synchronize access to the property or to use lazy initialization... but notice that `List<Character>` tells nothing about the `Client`. I don't know if there can be multiple calls to `LoadCharacterData` with different `Client` that may override each other work.

Comment: Thanks. I will take advantage of your experience and follow your advice. I already did it and everything works) I hope I willn't have any problems with that later. Thanks again.